# Exchange Upgrade - GAL won't load

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007, outlook, permissions

A recent reinstall of Exchange and now when I try to load the GAL in Outlook, error says The Bookmark is not valid.

I'm pretty sure this is a permissions issue, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: What versions of Exchange and Outlook please? GAL distribution has changed over the years.

Comment: Exchange 2007, Outlook 2003 and 2010

Comment: It sounds like an OAB issue to me. Try deleting the OAB files on the client machine.

Comment: It's doing it across our entire domain, with brand new clients as well.

Comment: I'm with Joe - it's always the damned OAB :-) Let me collect my thoughts, I might come up with something answer-worthy.

Comment: Something here worked....  I didn't find an OAB file, but I cleared out the Outlook directories under Application and Local Settings.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Problem came back, and is affecting several users.  Wiping the entire profile does not resolve it, but sometimes it's intermittent.  Any ideas?

Comment: @derjur did you read my answer? That had ideas in it. Did anything help? What about the logs I asked you to check - do they say anything?

Comment: Yes I did.  Thanks Ben.  I turned up the logging and I'm running a regeneration overnight.  I will check the logs in the morning, as now I'm having an (unrelated) vpn issue and can't even log in to check.  I'll comment on your answer as I get details.

Comment: Restarted Exchange and our DC this morning.  Address book was loading for a while.  Then it suddenly stopped with "The Bookmark is invalid" error.  Restarting the System Attendant Service on the Exchange box, wiping the local user profile, and regenerating the OAB seem to work sometimes, but the issue comes back.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have some OAB issues, since this is what Outlook actually uses when you're in cached mode.

It would be good to turn up the diagnostic logging for the OAB generation process and do a manual rebuild of the OAB. Hopefully the error will come to light in the event log. If you need to paste warnings/errors from your OAB Generation process into your original question, please feel free. When you're done with this, don't forget to turn the logs back down to normal.

It could be your OAB generation server is not what you expect and you need to move the OAB generation server to your new one.

If your OAB is being distributed solely by public folders, ensure the public folder database is mounted and available.

Answer (score 0):

In ESM go to the Properties of the Global Address List and ensure that "Authenticated Users" have the appropriate permissions.